# ms word 2013 massively increases file size of images inserted into new word document

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I've compressed a lot of pngs in gimp using a web optimised palette. When these are saved in word whether as .doc or html the images are increased in size eg from 12kb to 99kb. The only work around I can think of is to manually rename all original images (to match names given by Word) and put them into the associated html folder in place of the corrupted images. Any tips much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the compressed pngs viewed with HEX-editor plugin for Notepad++ shows that the 'critical chunks' that define pixel dimensions and pallet (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics) IHDR and PLTE are missing. Using IrfanView (may also be possible with Gimp- I had started with svg file format) solved this problem.